# How do I deal with my database id when I enter the id data to continue the data that has been deleted

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-5

**This is my controller code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Datakaryawan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class DatakaryawanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::paginate(4);
        return view('data-karyawan', ['data' => $data]);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::all();
        return view('data-karyawan-add', ['data' => $data]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Datakaryawan::create($request->all());

        if ($data) {
            Session::flash('status', 'success');
            Session::flash('message', 'Berhasil menambah data karyawan');
        }
        return redirect('data-karyawan');
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Datakaryawan::findorfail($id);
        return view('data-karyawan-edit', ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Datakaryawan::findorfail($id);
        $id->update($request->all()); 
        return redirect('/data-karyawan');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Datakaryawan::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return redirect()->to('/data-karyawan')->with('success', 'Berhasil menghapus data karyawan');
    }
}
```

**This is the default view**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrzEn.png)

**When I delete it, the id is 1, the id 2 doesn't become id 1, but it stays id 2**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkADm.png)

**After that I added new data, and the id instead follows the existing table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J90xV.png)

Comment: Yes, that's how databases work. Deleting an older id does not renumber the results.  If you rewrite the ID, then you'll run into a whole lot of race conditions and mismatched data.

Comment: @aynber So it's not because of an error or anything, but it's how the database works, isn't there a solution for that?

Comment: I you send your car to junk yard, registration numbers don't change in cascade to fill the gap. That's how identifiers work. If you want a row count, you can calculate it on the fly.

Comment: No. Rewriting ids is a Very Bad Idea. It's how the database keeps track of all of the records.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the database behaves.
I guess you have a blade file with a foreach loop where you get the specific item and then you call something like `$item->id`. Just change that to `$loop->index` and you should get the behaviour you want.

when you request delete/update the data of a row don't use this `$loop->index` but use the actual id, you can just add the id in a data attribute like for example:

```
<div class"row" data-id="{{$item->id}}"...
```